# Websocket Handshake Error

Tags: php, jquery, websocket, xampp

I am trying to do this on my xampp install.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

When I get to the shell and type the php -q htdocs\socket\server\startDeamon.php I get this ...

```
2012-10-17 08:42:11 System: Socket Resource id #7 created.
2012-10-17 08:42:11 System: Socket bound to localhost:8000.
2012-10-17 08:42:11 System: Start listening on Socket.

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdoc
s\socket\server\socketWebSocket.class.php on line 35

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdoc
s\socket\server\socketWebSocket.class.php on line 35
2012-10-17 08:42:31 WebSocket: Resource id #8 disconnected!

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdoc
s\socket\server\socketWebSocket.class.php on line 35

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdoc
s\socket\server\socketWebSocket.class.php on line 35
```

What could be the problem, is the code old?

this is line 35 of socketWebSocket.class.php

```
$num_sockets = socket_select($changed_sockets,$write=NULL,$exceptions=NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: Post line 35 of the code. But I'd reconsider using e.g. nodejs+socket.io for websockets instead of a rather minimalistic PHP-based implementation.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$write=NULL;
$exceptions=NULL;
$num_sockets = socket_select($changed_sockets,$write,$exceptions,0);
```